# Cannot find symbol on comparable array

Tags: java, arrays, compare, cannot-find-symbol

I have to build a stack of comparable objects from a given interface.
Inside the class, this is my constructor:

```
public S()
{
   Comparable[] arr = new Comparable[INITSIZE];
   size = 0;
}
```

Now, in every method where the array appears, for example:

```
public void push(Comparable x)
{
   arr[size++] = x;
}
```

I get cannot find symbol error related to arr while compiling. Why?

Comment: Cannot find *which* symbol? What is the exact error message?

Comment: `Comparable[] arr = null;` declare inside of class but outside of any method or constructor and Initialize `arr = new Comparable[INITSIZE];` it in constructor. Otherwise `arr` not visible to other methods since it is local variable in constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get cannot find symbol error related to arr while compiling.

Declare `arr` inside of the class but outside of any method or constructor.

```
public class S{

    Comparable[] arr;  
}
```

and Initialize it in constructor.

```
public S()
{
    arr = new Comparable[INITSIZE];
}
```

Otherwise `arr` not visible to other methods and you will get cannot find symbol error related to `arr` while compiling since it is local variable in constructor.

```
public class S{

        Comparable[] arr = null; 

        public S()
        {
             arr = new Comparable[INITSIZE];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why initialize the array with `null`, if you assign it in the constructor?

Comment: Also think about making it `private` and, if you like, `final`.